# Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<EnumValue[]>' : source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Have issues assigning an `Observable<EnumValue[]>` to `Observable<EnumValue[]>`.

```
fetchContactLocationStates()
{
   this.contactLocationStates$ = this.enumValues$
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
     .subscribe(x => x.filter((p) => p.CategoryId === EnumCategory.State));
}
```

Error:

> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<EnumValue[]>' : source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contactLocationStates$` expects the value of `Observable<EnumValue[]>`. You shouldn't call the `.subscribe()`.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

fetchContactLocationStates()
{
   this.contactLocationStates$ = this.enumValues$
     .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.destroy$),
       map((x) => x.filter((p) => p.CategoryId === EnumCategory.State))
     );
}
```

Comment: It appears that `x` is of type Array, so I cannot use `x.CategoryId`

Comment: So `filter` is not a valid option. Not only because it returns an array but it Is also depreciated. however, I replaced filter with `map` and it works fine. Change your answer to map and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hi @CorrieJanse, apologies for the previous answer, and thanks for pointing it out. Ya, your propose changes are correct.